# matrix,distance, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, distance

```
function getDistance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2){
    var R = 6371; //KM
    var d = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R
        return d    
};


var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
alert(items[0][0]); // 1​​


document.write(getDistance(items[0][0],items[1][1],items[1][2],items[2][2]));
document.write(getDistance(45,35,41,35));
```

Why can I not call my array element (items) in function `getDistance`?

Comment: Since you're new to Stackoverflow you should know that you should accept answers by clicking the green check mark if that question has been helpful enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no array elements for which the inner dimension has key `[2]`. Your 3 sub-arrays all have only two elements, so their available keys are only `[0],[1]`.

You therefore can't access non-existant elements like `items[1][2]` or `items[2][2]` when those sub-arrays' last keys are `items[1][1]` and `items[2][1]` respectively.

You tested `items[0][0]`, but see what happens when you try `items[2][2]`

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
console.log(items[0][0]); // 1​​
console.log(items[2][2]); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getDistance(, ... items[1][2], items[2][2]);
```

There is no third element in the array `item[1]` or `items[2]`.